# How to fix this issue with render flex overflowed error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-renderflex-error

I try to use `Expanded` and `Flexible` and cannot be fixed How to fix this issue with render flex overflowed error

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
class CommPage extends StatefulWidget {
const CommPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
State<CommPage> createState() => _CommPageState();
}
class _CommPageState extends State<CommPage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
bool isliked = true;
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 50, 60, 50),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down)),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 10, 0),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/55.png',
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  height: 50,
                  width: 50,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                'Making your best out of a bad day',
                maxLines: 3,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 17,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Container(
        width: size.width,
        height: 60,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Text(
            'Comments (56)',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 30,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 10,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Flexible(
              flex: 5,
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 16.0,
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                              '_loadedPhotos[index]["thumbnailUrl"],'),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 30, 0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          'User Name',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 16,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 7,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          '3 hour ago',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 12,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 14,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,consectetur adipiscing elit. dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
                          // maxLines: 3,
                          // overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                          // softWrap: true,
                          // textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey,
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Divider(
                          thickness: 1,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(isliked
                                  ? Icons.favorite_border
                                  : Icons.favorite),
                              onPressed: () {
                                setState(() {
                                  isliked = !isliked;
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                            Text(
                              'Like',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 14,
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 25,
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                icon: Icon(
                                  FontAwesomeIcons.comment,
                                  size: 20,
                                )),
                            Text(
                              'Comments',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 14,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwFyr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrap your `Flexible` with a `Container`.